# Facebook open graph custom stories and custom objects with js sdk

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to devellop a facebook app using custom stories and objects using js sdk but i met some problems.

What i try to achive is to create a story like:
"John played football on MyApp.- with Mike and Kate at city stadium"
under the text to be an image, a title and some description and on click goes to a link.

I have defined my action "Play" and my object "Football".

The action code facebook gives is:

```
FB.api(
  'me/myapp:play',
  'post',
  {
    football: "http://samples.ogp.me/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  },
  function(response) {}
);
```

The object code facebook gives is:

```
FB.api(
  'me/objects/myapp:football',
  'post',
  {
    app_id: myappid,
    type: "myapp:football",
    url: "http://samples.ogp.me/xxxxxxxxxxx",
    title: "Sample Football",
    image: "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png",
    description: ""
  },
  function(response) {}
);
```

However I used it as follows:
HTML:

```
<a onclick="playFootball();" href="#">Play Football</a>
```

JS:

```
function playFootball() {
    FB.api(
            'me/testapp-radu:play',
            'post',
            {   
                tags: "xxxxxx, xxxxxx,",
                place: "https://www.facebook.com/pages/MyPlace/xxxxxx?ref=br_rs",
                football: "http://samples.ogp.me/xxxxxx",
                image: "http://www.peter-ould.net/wp-content/uploads/soccer-ball.jpg",
                privacy: {'value': 'SELF'}
            },
    function(response) {}); 
}
```

and the result was this:
http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/337/yj9o.jpg

1. I was unable to change "played a football" into "played football".
2. The title was unchanged despite use of property title, same applies to url and description, also I tried to use an object but still no results.

If someone could help me solve these 2 problems I wold be really gratefull, or at least point me to some basic tutorials (facebook documentation sometimes is confuzing for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using **football** as a wrong way of specifying your story. You are using name of the instance instead of class. Let me explain.

Following are the two scenarios I could come up with:

1. Your app is about games that users play. So in this case your object becomes **game** and football will be the `name` of the game. So now your story reads like:

   "A played football with B and C via your_app" since you will be providing the `name` property of the **game** object, facebook will select the right story sentence for you
2. Your app is about sports products, in which case your object becomes **sport_product** or **product** and football will be an instance of sport product. But in this case an action of **play** does not make any sense. So lets say **buy** is an action. So now your story reads like:

   "A bought football with B and C via your_app"

Also if you think about it **football** does not make sense as an object. What would be the value of the `name` property of football, "Kaka's football" - does not make sense. Think in terms of a generic class of object rather an instance. (Think `Movie` not **Inception**).

[Sample Story](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1mgkmsHvYt-ZERGdGFia292Tmc)

Hope this makes sense!